# Gorgeous web buttons with proper behavior, can it be done?

Tags: css, button, internet-explorer

For my application, I wanted to style the submit buttons nicely. With normal CSS, I managed to get it to look good in Firefox, and horrible in IE. Then I saw this blog entry:

http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/liquid-color-adjustable-css-buttons/

Using that technique you get gorgeous buttons, in pretty much all browsers. However, there are also a few accessibility issues:

- Since it uses links instead of real HTML input or button elements, clicking the button does not submit the form. This is easily resolved using Javascript, but it would be ideal if the submit button works without Javascript enabled.
- Another issue is that hitting [ENTER] does not submit the form. A dirty hack is to include an invisible input element of type "submit" or "image".

Basically what I want is perhaps the impossible: The quality of the styling as seen in the blog entry, yet implemented using normal elements so that I get normal behavior.

**Do I really have to chose between dirty hacks or poor styling?**

Every button styling tutorial that I have seen so far has sub optimal results in IE :(

Comment: you might like http://stopdesign.com/archive/2009/02/04/recreating-the-button.html

Comment: Bear in mind that it's something of a myth that screen readers don't work with Javascript.

Comment: And as Graphicdivine says below, you probably shouldn't be restyling your form controls anyway, unless you have no choice in the matter.

Answer (score 7):

> Do I really have to chose between dirty hacks or poor styling?

No, you could use Javascript like the rest of us. Load in your standard form (complete with submit-button), and then use neatly-written Javascript to dynamically "fix" some of the ugly elements. I'd suggest evaluating the jQuery framework for this type of thing if you wish to use clean code, and get cross-browser support.

Comment: If you can apply CSS that fixes the ugly elements dynamically, then you can just as well apply it statically. No need for Javascript at all. Besides, the OP explicitly states he wants the submit button to work without Javascript, so he probably wants it to look good without Javascript as well.

Comment: The point is that you use ugly normal buttons, then use JS to replace them with pretty buttons that require JS. If they don't have JS, they have ugly buttons, and the swap isn't made. If they do have JS, then the swap is made, and it's "OK" to use JS to handle the clicks.

Comment: And my point is that you don't have to use ugly buttons to begin with. You can have pretty buttons right away, purely with CSS, so that there's no need to swap anything at all, whether the user has JS enabled or not.

Comment: RegDwight, that depends on what your definition of "pretty buttons" is. Granted, CSS can do a lot on its own (I rarely use anything else for forms), but there's a lot CSS simply cannot do. I'm merely acknowledging that there are scenarios where javascript is the solution.

Answer (score 3):

See [this tutorial](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/update_styling_the_button_element_with_css_sliding_doors_now_with_image_spr/). No JavaScript, no links instead of buttons, works in IE6 through IE8.

Comment: I think that's probably the best possible approach if you're really averse to using javascript.

Answer (score 2):

> *For my application, I wanted to style the submit buttons nicely. With normal CSS, I managed to get it to look good in Firefox, and horrible in IE.*

For IE you need to add `overflow: visible;` to get rid of "unexplainable" padding. That's basically all you need to take into account for IE (as long as you're not in quirksmode).

> *Then I saw this blog entry:*

Wouldn't go for it. Just stick to `<button type="submit">` or `<input type="submit">` with a good shot of CSS. You can even use CSS background images on those buttons. I wouldn't grab Javascript for layout issues as well, because that may cause "wtf?" experiences during page load when the user instantly sees parts of page rapidly changing. Just use CSS the smart way.

Comment: Agreed. YMMV with IE6, but IE7+ and other real browsers let you do some decent stuff with buttons.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to transport the liquid button thingy you mention into a `<button type="submit"></button>` setup by replacing the surrounding `<div>`s by `button` elements, and the `<a>`s by `<span>`s.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you do.

Except that it's not 'poor styling', it's browser chrome.  Form elements are part of the browser.  'Styling' them confuses the user and impedes usability. Seriously, just leave them well alone.

No matter how far you go with input styling, you will inevitably hit the brick wall of the file upload element, which is pretty much impossible to style. And if you can't style them all, why style any of them.

Seriously, this is akin to styling scrollbars.  Don't bother.

Comment: GMail styles the upload element. And I did it too :) ... But I agree that it is difficult.

Comment: Daniel: Cross-browser? Webkit?

Comment: Agreed, you should always think very carefully before going against established conventions in web design and form buttons are definitely one of those.

Comment: @graphicdivine: There are some cheeky ways to do it cross-browser: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html or http://www.shauninman.com/archive/2007/09/10/styling_file_inputs_with_css_and_the_dom. However they do come with their own bag of disadvantages... I still agree with your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you don't have to use Javascript or anything similar. You may use buttons as well.

Continuing from http://www.sohtanaka.com/web-design/liquid-color-adjustable-css-buttons/ make the following changes:

1. Add the following to the CSS declaration

   .btn button {
       float: left;
       height: 40px;
       background: url(images/btn_stretch.png) repeat-x left top;
       line-height: 40px;
       padding: 0 10px;
       color: #fff;
       font-size: 1em;
       text-decoration: none;
       border: 0;
   }
2. Add the following to the HTML code:

   <div class="btn btn_learnmore">
       <button>You Should Give it a Try</button>
       <span></span>
   </div>

**Edit:** also add margin: 0 to the button css declaration.

Comment: I was hopeful about this, but it really screws up the styling. Both in Firefox and IE it ignores the stretch overlay and also adds a bottom margin to the buttom. And again, firefox really renders text between button elements in a weird way.

Comment: It looks fine on 5 browsers I tested it: IE, FF, Chrome, Opera and Safari. IE and Opera still misplace the text when you click the button, which is a nice touch. Why you do think the styling is broken? Did you use border:0 and margin:0?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a normal submit button, and use JavaScript to swap it out for a pretty JS-enhanced button. This way, you only use JavaScript where you know it'll be supported and you won't leave NoScript users with a broken page

Answer (score 0):

Check out YUI's buttons... they seem to have figured this out

http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/button/btn_example01.html

Comment: Definitely interesting, but that approach still requires Javascript.

Comment: Yeah, it does, but with Firebug in firefox, you can see what CSS the javascript has applied after the fact, and just copy it and fine tune it to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I do believe there is an `<input type="image" src="ButtonBg.jpg" />`

http://webdesign.about.com/cs/forms/a/aaformsubmit.htm

I've never really used it though.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at Awesome Buttons?

http://www.zurb.com/article/266/super-awesome-buttons-with-css3-and-rgba

They are pretty awesome, can be applied to links or buttons and look good in all the browsers I've tried (ie6 has a few little issues, but a little css just for them fixes things up).

Answer (score 0):

We just use CSS to make some very nice looking buttons.  Works in IE6 - 8 and Firefox.

```
input.blueButton
{
    background-image: url(../Images/blueButton.gif);
    width: 80px;
    height: 21px;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: White;
    background-color: Transparent;
    border-style: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    margin: 0 3px;
}
```